# Filtering runtime processes to see if is a runaway process

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to improve readability and performance, either by reordering the logic of my code or just syntactically being smarter.  Basically, I gather the running processes from Db and then I parse each process and go through he conditions for which the process might be runaway. I always have to go to another server find out the average run time for that process and I use that value as the norm. I send alerts, SMS, email, report if it is runaway. But I'm not sure if I'm doing this in smart way. I think I should avoid SQL queries until the last step on which I need to get normal run time average to see if it actually is runaway.

```
# compile a regex of the keys to ignore
keyIgnoreRe = compile('^/stale_jobs/.+')

def send_alert(job, past_due=0):
    #send alert code

def parse_job_definition(defin):
    # parse out the job definition from the bob job object
    jobdefstr = str(defin)
    if 'json:' in jobdefstr:
        jobdef = simplejson.loads(jobdefstr[5:])
    else:
        jobdef = yaml.load(jobdefstr)

    return jobdef

def parsenotifyees(notifyees):
    notifyeeslist = notifyees if type(notifyees) == list else [notifyees]
    to = ''
    for addr in notifyeeslist:
        if '@' in addr:
            if to:
                to += ', %s' % addr
            else:
                to = addr
        else:
            for alias in (conn.search(attrList=['mail'], mailNickName=addr)):
                if to:
                    to += ','
                to += ','.join(alias.get('mail'))
    return to

def get_SMS_jobs(SMS_server, topic_SMS, filter_str):
    SMS_client = SMSClient(SMS_server)
    SMS_job_list = []
    for attempt in range(3):
        try:
            SMS_jobs = SMS_client()
        except Exception:
            time.sleep((attempt+1)*10) #try up to a minute, otherwise, give up
        else:
            return SMS_jobs
    else:
        return None   
    return SMS_job_list


def is_run_away_job(cur_run, avg_run):         
    #nums in secs
    if avg_run < 300:
        #Check for 5 minutes or less jobs
        if cur_run >= 1200 + avg_run:
            return True
    elif 300 <= avg_run < 900:
        #Check for 5 to 15 minutes jobs
        if cur_run >= 1800 + avg_run:
            return True
    elif 900 <= avg_run < 1800:
        #Check for 15 to 30 minutes jobs
        if cur_run >= 2700 + avg_run:
            return True
    elif 1800 <= avg_run < 10800:
        #Check for 30 minutes to 3 hours jobs
        if cur_run >= 2 * avg_run:
            return True
    else:
        #Check for 3 hours or more jobs
        if cur_run >= 1.5 * avg_run:
            return True
    return False

def change_format_num(runTime):

    #runTime = '%s Hours:Minutes:Seconds' % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(runTime))

    current_time = time.gmtime(runTime) 
    hours = int(time.strftime("%H", current_time))
    days = hours / 24
    hours = hours % 24

    time_string = ""
    if days > 0:
      time_string += "%d Days " % days
    if hours > 0:
      time_string += "%d Hours " % hours

    time_string += time.strftime("%M Minutes %S Seconds", current_time)
    runTime = time_string


    # fmt = '{0.days} days {0.hours} hours {0.minutes} minutes {0.seconds} seconds'
    # runTime = fmt.format(rd(seconds=runTime))

    return runTime


def send_email(flaged_jobs_name, list_notifyees, avg_runtime, current_runtime ):
    #email code


def send_SMS(job, cur_runtime, avg_time):
    #send SMS code

def send_report(size_batch, num_rejected, num_of_runnaway, now, end_time,SMS_jobs,jobs_disabled):
    #send report code

def get_jobs_already_alerted(batchDate):
    #jobs already parsed save in DB          

def is_job_ignored(job_name, job_definition, alerted_job_list):

    if keyIgnoreRe.match(job_name):
        ignore_job_list.append(job_name)
        return True

    if 'DISABLE_LONGRUN_MONITOR' in job_definition:
        disable_job_list.append(job_name)
        return True

    # ignore jobs that match the keyIgnoreRe
    if alerted_job_list and job_name in alerted_job_list:
        alerted_job_list.append(job_name)
        return True

    return False

def get_notifyees(jobdef):
    origNotifyeesList = jobdef['notifyees'] if isinstance(jobdef['notifyees'], list) else [jobdef['notifyees']]
    notifyeesList = []
    for notifyee in origNotifyeesList:
        if 'disabled' not in notifyee:
            notifyeesList.append(notifyee)

    notifyeesList = parsenotifyees(notifyeesList)
    return notifyeesList

def run():
    counter_rejected = 0
    counter_long_running_job = 0

    ET = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    now = datetime.datetime.now(ET)
    logging.info("This job was started at (EST):  %s" % now)

    dates = #parsed from DB

    for batchDate in dates:

        alerted_job_list = get_jobs_already_alerted(batchDate)

        running_jobs_batch = get_SMS_jobs()

        if not running_jobs_batch:
            continue #we'll skip that batch

        size_batch = ('The batch size: %s' % (len(running_jobs_batch)))

        reported_SMS_list = []
        reported_disabled_list = []

        for job in running_jobs_batch:

            job_name = job.get('name')

             if not is_job_ignored(job_name, alerted_SMS_jobs) or keyAcceptRe.match(job_name):        
            #logging.info( '%s (%s)' % (job.get('name'), job.get('state')))
            try:

                dataSet = data.Engine.execute(SQL STATEMENT)

                if dataSet:        
                    average_runtime = float(dataSet[0][0])         
                else:
                    counter_rejected += 1
                    logging.warning('%s not in DB' % job_name)
                    continue
            except Exception, e:
                counter_rejected_DB += 1
                logging.info('Exception: %s' % e)      
                continue

            logging.info('Average RUNTIME: %s for Job: %s ' % (average_runtime, job_name))

            start_time = float(job.get('starttime'))
            current_runtime = time.time() - start_time

            #if (not is_already_alerted(job.get('name'), batchDate)) and is_run_away_job(float(job.get('starttime')), average_runtime):
            if is_run_away_job(current_runtime, average_runtime):      
                notifyeesList = get_notifyees(parse_job_definition(job.get('definition')))
                if notifyeesList and not is_job_ignored(job_name, alerted_SMS_jobs)
                    send_email(job_name, notifyeesList, average_runtime, current_runtime)
                send_alert(job, time.time() - average_runtime)
                counter_long_running_job += 1 
                send_SMS(job, current_runtime, average_runtime)       

            else:
                #logging.info('%s is not running away' % job.get('name'))
                continue    

    end_time = datetime.datetime.now(ET)           
    send_report(size_batch, counter_rejected, counter_long_running_job, now, end_time, reported_SMS_list, reported_disabled_list)
    # Explicitly tell it to exit to avoid locked threads from keeping the job alive
    os._exit(0)

class SMSClient(object):
    #SMS CLIENT CODE

def main():
    run()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `parsenotifyees`

In this code, the need to check whether anything was added to the `to` variable is awkward and error-prone:

```
to = ''
for addr in notifyeeslist:
    if '@' in addr:
        if to:
            to += ', %s' % addr
        else:
            to = addr
    else:
        for alias in (conn.search(attrList=['mail'], mailNickName=addr)):
            if to:
                to += ','
            to += ','.join(alias.get('mail'))
return to
```

It will be simpler and safer to accumulate the list of recipients in a list and join by `,` at the end:

```
to = []
for addr in notifyeeslist:
    if '@' in addr:
        to.append(addr)
    else:
        aliases = conn.search(attrList=['mail'], mailNickName=addr)
        to.extend([alias.get('mail') for alias in aliases])
return ', '.join(to)
```

#### `get_SMS_jobs`

The name of this method suggests that it would return a list,
or some kind of iterable.
But actually it may return `None` (in case of failure),
which can create a burden on callers:
before iterating on the result,
callers must check if it's `None`.
Unless there's a good reason otherwise,
methods that return lists should return empty list instead of `None`.

> ```
> def get_SMS_jobs(SMS_server, topic_SMS, filter_str):
>     SMS_client = SMSClient(SMS_server)
>     SMS_job_list = []
>     for attempt in range(3):
>         try:
>             SMS_jobs = SMS_client()
>         except Exception:
>             time.sleep((attempt+1)*10) #try up to a minute, otherwise, give up
>         else:
>             return SMS_jobs
>     else:
>         return None   
>     return SMS_job_list
> ```

Some other minor problems with this code:

- `SMS_job_list` is unused
- `SMS_jobs` seems unnecessary
- try-except-else is kind of confusing [to many people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138232/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-try-except-else-in-python), it's better to avoid when there is a good alternative
- the expression `(attempt+1)*10` is too tightly packed: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends spaces around operators
- another tiny PEP8 tip: put 2 spaces before `#` in inline comments

How about rewriting like this:

```
def get_SMS_jobs(SMS_server, topic_SMS, filter_str):
    for attempt in range(3):
        try:
            return SMSClient(SMS_server)()
        except Exception:
            time.sleep((attempt + 1) * 10)  # try up to a minute, otherwise, give up
    return []
```